# Margin appears on sides of navbar in mobile mode when carousel does not exist

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with the Bootstrap navbar for the carousel theme. The problem is when I go into mobile mode (basically sizing down the window), the navbar has white space on the sides, something that I don't want to happen. Is this probably because it depends on the Carousel `div`?

[image: navbar extends to full width of page]
With the Carousel thing, the navbar won't have white space.

[image: navbar has margins on the sides]
There is white space on the other pages on the sides when there is no carousel.

Is there any way to fix this? I tried removing the container styling, but that just ruins the whole page.

Comment: It would be better if you give us some code. Try [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Ok! Here's a link that may help. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iw4f-yRf7RU). You should get familiar with jsfiddle! Gonna "help" your questions in stack overflow!

Comment: I fixed it with the row tag; apparently that was needed. I appreciate all your help though! Definitely will keep that in mind next time... JSFiddle... Interesting concept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going out a limb here, and guessing you haven't wrapped  the navbar in a 'row' div.  The row div has negative margins which counteract the padding on the container div.

```
<div class ='container'>
     <div class ='row'>
          <div class ='nav_bar'></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never mind! I put row tag in the wrong place... Thanks!